# How to hidde/remove background image of previous div

Tags: html, css

I got a list of images and loop through it to display in html file

```
{% for photo in photos %}
    <div class="swiper-slide cover"
        style="background-image: url({{photo.url}});background-size: contain;">
        <a href={{photo.url}} data-fancybox="gallery" class="zoom"><span
        class="icon-search"></span></a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But when I display an image over another and because the size of those images are different, I can see the previous image behind the current one. Is there any way to hide the image behind?

[image]

Comment: Will you include an image of the slider with the stacked images?

Comment: I was edit my post with the link to image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make height and width same.

suppose

```
.img {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width:  100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-size:     cover;
}
```

Comment: I'd like to keep the image in original size. If it not fit the screen, will have the black area in 2 sides, like in the image i attach...

Comment: just add this  background-size: cover;

Answer (score 0):

Provide a `background-color` for the `swiper-slide` class. That will hide the previous image containers.

```
.swiper-slide {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: @LêThanhTú Please approve my answer if that works for you.